# iTextSharp Cómo alinear dos tablas, una al lado de otra

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itextsharp

Buenas noches compañeros, como verán, mi caso es el que se muestra en la imagen adjunta. Tengo una cabecera la cual estoy usando una clase que hereda `PdfPageEventHelper`.

Y debajo de eso tengo dos tablas las cuales quiero colocar en paralelo, una al lado de otra, pero la primera se solapa o se sobrepone con mi cabecera. ¿Podrían decirme por favor qué está mal en mi código? Muchísimas gracias de antemano

Estoy usando **VB.NET ASP.NET**

```
  Public Sub plantillaParaExportar()
    Dim imagepath As String = Server.MapPath("images")
    Dim document As New Document(PageSize.LETTER) ', 88.0F, 88.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F) '
    Dim ev As New ITextEvents
    Using memoryStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()

        document.AddTitle("Ventas")
        document.AddAuthor("iTuHand")
        document.AddCreationDate()
        document.AddSubject("Modulo Gerencial")
        'document.SetMargins(28.5, 28.5, 70, 35)'

        Dim cell As PdfPCell = Nothing
        Dim phrase As Phrase = Nothing
        Dim colorLine As iTextSharp.text.BaseColor = Nothing
        Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream)
        Dim table As PdfPTable = Nothing

        ev.pHeader = "VENTAS"
        ev.pSubtitle1 = "Comparativo Del: " & Me.txtDel1.Text & " al " & Me.txtAl1.Text
        ev.pSubtitle2 = "Del " & Me.txtDel2.Text & " al " & Me.txtAl2.Text

        writer.PageEvent = ev
        document.Open()


        table = New PdfPTable(2)
        table.SetWidths(New Single() {2.0F, 1.5F})
        table.TotalWidth = 200.0F
        table.LockedWidth = True
        table.SpacingBefore = 30.0F
        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT

        addCell(table, "INDICADORES DE VENTAS", 1, 2, eAlineado.centro, True)

        addCell(table, "Margen de Utilidad Operativa", 1, 1, eAlineado.izquierda, False)
        addCell(table, Me.txtMarUtilidadOpe.Text, 1, 1, eAlineado.derecha, False)

        addCell(table, "Devoluciones s/Ventas Totales", 1, 1, eAlineado.izquierda, False)
        addCell(table, Me.txtDevSinVentasTot.Text, 1, 1, eAlineado.derecha, False)

        addCell(table, "Indices de Costos de Ventas", 1, 1, eAlineado.izquierda, False)
        addCell(table, Me.txtIndicesCostosVentas.Text, 1, 1, eAlineado.derecha, False)

        addCell(table, "Indices de Gastos Totales", 1, 1, eAlineado.izquierda, False)
        addCell(table, Me.txtIndicesGastosTotales.Text, 1, 1, eAlineado.derecha, False)

        'table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left, document.Top, writer.DirectContent)'
        'table.WriteSelectedRows(0, table.Rows.Count, 400, 400, writer.DirectContent)'
        document.Add(table)

        table = New PdfPTable(3)
        table.SetWidths(New Single() {2.0F, 1.5F, 1.5F})
        table.TotalWidth = 250.0F
        table.LockedWidth = True
        table.SpacingBefore = 30.0F
        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT

        addCell(table, "", 1, 1, eAlineado.centro, True)
        addCell(table, "ANTERIOR", 1, 1, eAlineado.centro, True)
        addCell(table, "ACTUAL", 1, 1, eAlineado.centro, True)

        addCell(table, "Ingresos por ventas", 1, 1, eAlineado.izquierda, False)
        addCell(table, Me.txtIngresosVentasAnt.Text, 1, 1, eAlineado.derecha, False)
        addCell(table, Me.txtIngresosVentasAct.Text, 1, 1, eAlineado.derecha, False)

        addCell(table, "Costos de Ventas", 1, 1, eAlineado.izquierda, False)
        addCell(table, Me.txtCostosVentasAnt.Text, 1, 1, eAlineado.derecha, False)
        addCell(table, Me.txtCostosVentasAct.Text, 1, 1, eAlineado.derecha, False)

        addCell(table, "Margen de Utilidad Bruta", 1, 1, eAlineado.izquierda, False)
        addCell(table, Me.txtMargenUtilidadBrutaAnt.Text, 1, 1, eAlineado.derecha, False)
        addCell(table, Me.txtMargenUtilidadBrutaAct.Text, 1, 1, eAlineado.derecha, False)

        addCell(table, "Comisiones", 1, 1, eAlineado.izquierda, False)
        addCell(table, Me.txtComisiones.Text, 1, 1, eAlineado.derecha, False)
        addCell(table, "", 1, 1, eAlineado.derecha, False)

        addCell(table, "Publicidad", 1, 1, eAlineado.izquierda, False)
        addCell(table, Me.txtPublicidad.Text, 1, 1, eAlineado.derecha, False)
        addCell(table, "", 1, 1, eAlineado.derecha, False)

        addCell(table, "Promociones", 1, 1, eAlineado.izquierda, False)
        addCell(table, Me.txtPromociones.Text, 1, 1, eAlineado.derecha, False)
        addCell(table, "", 1, 1, eAlineado.derecha, False)

        'table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left + 200, document.Top, writer.DirectContent)'

        document.Add(table)

        document.Close()
        Dim fileName As String = "ventas" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString() & ".pdf"
        Dim bytes As Byte() = memoryStream.ToArray()
        memoryStream.Close()
        Response.Clear()
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & fileName)
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
        Response.[End]()
        Response.Close()

    End Using
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que está todo bien, salvo por la clase `ITextEvents`, tal vez haya que llamar a alguno de sus métodos. Si publicas el código de dicha clase quizá se te pueda ayudar mejor.

Comment: pero mas bien yo creo que son las posiciones de las tablas, la primera tabla está ocupando la misma que del encabezado.